# HashMap is not storing object. Don't know why

Tags: java, object, hashmap

Below is my code:

```
package com.newyzon.controllers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;

import com.newyzon.beans.Cart;
import com.newyzon.beans.BookData;
import com.newyzon.beans.BookMeta;
import com.newyzon.beans.DisplayBookList;
import com.newyzon.services.*;

public class BooklistController {
LoginController lc;
Map<String, BookData> booklist = new HashMap<String, BookData>();

public BooklistController(LoginController lc) {
    this.lc = lc;
}
public void displayBookList(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException, ServiceException {
    BooksService bs = new BooksServiceLocator();
    Books books = bs.getBooksPort();

    //response.getWriter().append(books.getBook(1).getTitle());

    int quant = books.getSize();
    String output = "<br/>";
    for(int i=0; i < quant; i++) {
        Book bk = books.getBook(i);
        BookData bd = new BookData(bk.getId(), bk.getTitle(), bk.getAuthor(), bk.getPublisher());
        output += "<a href='Controller?task=addbook&bookid=" + bd.getId() + "'>" + bd.getTitle() + "</a><br/>";

        booklist.put("" + bd.getId(), bd);
    }

    DisplayBookList dbl = new DisplayBookList(output);

    request.getSession().setAttribute("displayBookList", dbl);

    lc.sendRedirectJsp("bookList", request, response); 
}
public void addToCart(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    String bookid = request.getParameter("bookid");
    BookData bk = booklist.get(bookid);

    // Add the book to the cart
    Cart cart = (Cart)request.getSession().getAttribute("cart");
    if(cart == null) {
        cart = new Cart();
        request.getSession().setAttribute("cart", cart);
    }
    BookMeta bm;
    if((bm = cart.contains(bk)) != null) {
        bm.setQuantity(bm.getQuantity() + 1);
    } else {
        bm = new BookMeta(bk, 1);
        cart.getBooks().add(bm);
    }
}
}
```

For some reason, the HashMap.put() is run, but the resultant booklist object contains no BookData objects, instead it just puts a null value in there.  I've debugged and checked to see that the parameter 'bd' contains a BookData object, (and it does), so why doesn't it end up in the hashmap?

Comment: What is the lifecycle of this controller? Do you get the same instance for subsequent requests? Should the `bookList` be stored in a session somewhere instead?

Comment: Does the map really contain a `null` for the value, or does just `booklist.get(bookid)` return `null` (which most likely means, that the `bookid` wasn't found).

Comment: How do you know that it doesn't "end up in the hashmap"? Do you mean that when `addToCart` runs there is nothing in the `booklist`? Or that the "booklist" JSP doesn't display anything?

Comment: Stored the booklist in the session object and now it works.  Thanks guys!

Comment: How do you mark an answer as a good answer on here?